# Custom systemd service that runs shell script at startup is inactive (dead)

Tags: bash, shell, systemd, ubuntu-18.04, systemctl

I made a systemd service that should run a script on startup. The script contains a couple echoes for power saving and a command to disable my bluetooth. It has executable rights.
When I start the service it has an inactive (dead) status. 
Here you can see my systemd service and the script that i am trying to run.

I already tried a crontab : @reboot ( sleep 90 ; sh /home/maxim/bin/power.sh )
Still didn't have the required results.

```
[Unit]
Description=Example systemd service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /bin/sh /home/maxim/bin/power.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The power.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host2
/link_power_management_policy'
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host3
/link_power_management_policy'
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host0
/link_power_management_policy'
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host1
/link_power_management_policy'
echo '1500' > '/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs'
rfkill block bluetooth
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you run the ExecStart Command on the command line successfully (as that user that would start the service), without sudo asking for a Password?

Comment: Why are there newlines in your file names?